# Windows XP Microsoft Update web page continuous reload loop

Tags: windows-update

So I go to update.microsoft.com.  Run the ActiveX, and then the page loads, and says Done on the status bar.  However, nothing happens.  Windows updater does not run on the page.  I have isntalled the latest MS Update agent.  Tried it in IE 7 and 8, and cannot get Win to update.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use http://windowsupdate.microsoft.com/ at first; after that, you can use the updater that's installed on your operating system by visiting that link. Please note that Windows XP no longer updates through a website, but rather on your computer in the control panel.

Answer (score 2):

This error was in my WindowsUpdate.log file, suggesting that the Windows Update web component was out of date:

```
FATAL: Update required for C:\WINDOWS\system32\wuweb.dll: target version = 7.2.6001.788, required version = 7.6.7600.256
```

The other methods suggested didn't work for me, but running the fixit tool from MS support did: http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9767096

You can also go to:
 http://support2.microsoft.com/fixit/

Answer (score 0):

Tom, that's not true for Windows XP.

The only workaround I've found that works consistently is to use the French update site to reinstall a working version of Microsoft Update. 
http://www.update.microsoft.com/microsoftupdate/v6/default.aspx?ln=fr
(Then you can reload update.microsoft.com normally)

Comment: I just tried this work around and it appears to no longer work (at least not for me)